# Find related user information for views, procedures, and other objects in SQL Server 2008 R2 and up

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I could have sworn I did this before from the sys views or data management views and found the info somewhere.  Yet I cannot locate my code and maybe I just did this with extended properties in the past to find that as everywhere online I am reading that this cannot be done except by tracing object creation.  Can anyone tell me how if they know can you find the user that created a procedure in TSQL in SQL server 2008 R2 or higher?

EG: I know that the sys.objects you can find the name of your object and when it was modified like so:

```
Select Top 10 *
from sys.objects o (nolock) 
where type = 'V'  -- View
and name like '%Finance%'  -- Finance in the name of the object somewhere
```

I know that there are two tables that have info on user accounts (I know one of the tables you used to get users from is being deprecated, not sure if it is one of these):

```
Select Top 10 *
from sys.server_principals p (nolock) 
where p.type = 'U'

Select top 10 *
from sysusers
```

Is there are way to find the SID of an object of who created it or similar?  I am finding 'NO' online when checking this site and others.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SQL Server doesn't keep track of who created a table, except in the default trace. So if it were created recently, you could find that information here:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(260);

SELECT 
   @path = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE([path]), 
   CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE([path])), 260)) + N'log.trc'
FROM    sys.traces
WHERE   is_default = 1;

SELECT LoginName, StartTime
FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable(@path, DEFAULT)
WHERE EventClass = 46 AND EventSubClass = 0 
AND databaseName = N'Your database name'
AND objectName = N'The table name you are trying to track down'
ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

However note that the default trace is a rolling trace, and how far back the data goes depends on the workload against your server. If you're trying to find out who created a table 6 months ago, you're quite likely out of luck.

You can capture this yourself, going forward, with things like [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx), [DDL triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx), or by periodically archiving the default trace ([I show how to do that here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2695/maintaining-sql-server-default-trace-historical-events-for-analysis-and-reporting/?utm_source-AaronBertrand)).